# Pandas plotting with date

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have to plot this graph
[click here to view it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6asg.png)

This is the fdata.csv file:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close
03-10-16,774.25,776.065002,769.5,772.559998
04-10-16,776.030029,778.710022,772.890015,776.429993
05-10-16,779.309998,782.070007,775.650024,776.469971
06-10-16,779,780.47998,775.539978,776.859985
07-10-16,779.659973,779.659973,770.75,775.080017
```

I have coded like this :

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('fdata.csv', index_col=0)
df.plot(x=df.index, y=df.columns)

plt.show()
```

But it shows an error:

```
KeyError: "Index(['03-10-16', '04-10-16', '05-10-16', 
'06-10-16', '07-10-16'], dtype='object', name='Date') 
not in index"
```

Can anyone explain and fix my issue ?

Comment: Just use `plt.plot` instead

Answer (score 0):

Create `DatetimeIndex` by add parameter `parse_dates` and then call [`DataFrame.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) by all columns:

```
df = pd.read_csv('fdata.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=[0])
df.plot()
```

[image: graph]